# How to setup Nginx reverse proxy for Jenkins

Tags: nginx, jenkins, redirect, reverse-proxy

I'm beginner in Nginx, and I faced with problem of setting up reverse proxy. My jenkins installed on 192.168.0.37:8080 and my nginx on 192.168.0.80. I want to access jenkins using 192.168.0.80/jenkins. Here is my /etc/nginx/conf.d/jenkins.conf content:

```
upstream jenkins {
  keepalive 32; # keepalive connections
  server 192.168.0.37:8080; # jenkins ip and port
}

# Required for Jenkins websocket agents
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}

server {
  listen          80;       # Listen on port 80 for IPv4 requests

  server_name     jenkins.example.com;  # replace 'jenkins.example.com' with your server domain name

  # this is the jenkins web root directory
  # (mentioned in the output of "systemctl cat jenkins")
  root            /var/cache/jenkins/war/;

  access_log      /var/log/nginx/jenkins.access.log;
  error_log       /var/log/nginx/jenkins.error.log;

  # pass through headers from Jenkins that Nginx considers invalid
  ignore_invalid_headers off;

  location ~ "^/static/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\/(.*)$" {
    # rewrite all static files into requests to the root
    # E.g /static/12345678/css/something.css will become /css/something.css
    rewrite "^/static/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\/(.*)" /$1 last;
  }

  location /userContent {
    # have nginx handle all the static requests to userContent folder
    # note : This is the $JENKINS_HOME dir
    root /var/lib/jenkins/;
    if (!-f $request_filename){
      # this file does not exist, might be a directory or a /**view** url
      rewrite (.*) /$1 last;
      break;
    }
    sendfile on;
  }

  location /jenkins {
      sendfile off;
      proxy_pass         http://jenkins;
      proxy_redirect     default;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;

      # Required for Jenkins websocket agents
      proxy_set_header   Connection        $connection_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header   Upgrade           $http_upgrade;

      proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

      #this is the maximum upload size
      client_max_body_size       10m;
      client_body_buffer_size    128k;

      proxy_connect_timeout      90;
      proxy_send_timeout         90;
      proxy_read_timeout         90;
      proxy_buffering            off;
      proxy_request_buffering    off; # Required for HTTP CLI commands
      proxy_set_header Connection ""; # Clear for keepalive
  }

}
```

When I try to enter `http://192.168.0.80/jenkins` I'm geting 404 Not Found.

Also I tried different approach:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.0.80;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /jenkins/ {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.37:8080/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /nexus/ {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.25:8081/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

In this case /nexus works perfectly fine, but /jenkins still return 404. Both machine using Ubuntu 22.04 Server. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Tried to add `--prefix=/jenkins` to JENKINS_ARGS, nothing changed

Comment: Can you have a look at the logs? Especially on the jenkins logs and have a look how the requests do look like it's receiving and how they should look like to serve successfully? Or if it not gets any requests at all - then you should have a look at the nginx access/error logs.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to configure Jenkins with the `/jenkins` context path. You can do this by passing a launch parameter `--prefix=/jenkins`. If you are on docker you can pass it like below.

```
docker run --name myjenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --env JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins" jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Else you can export the following env variable before stating the Jenkin service.

```
export JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins"
```

Once that's done a simple Nginx rule like below should work for you.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jenkins.ycr.com;

    location /jenkins {
            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080/ http://jenkins.ycr.com/;
        }
}
```

Comment: Still having the same issue 404.

`2023/07/30 19:30:01 [error] 521541#521541: *447 open()` `"/usr/share/nginx/html/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.0.48,` `server: 192.168.0.80, request: "GET /login?from=%2F HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.0.80"` `referrer: "http://192.168.0.80/jenkins/"`

Comment: I'd be looking at /usr/share/nginx/html/login and why isn't it connecting to it, does it exist?